# Understanding loading JSON convert to array Javascript

Tags: json, load, get, eval

I have the following JSON which forms a site map at the bottom of a HTML page:

```
var loadPages = { 'pageData' : [
    {   
        'loadInTo'      :    '#aboutUs',
        'url'           :   'http://www.website.co.uk/aboutUs.html',
        'urlSection'    :   '#aboutUs' 
    },
    {   
        'loadInTo'      :    '#whatWeDo',
        'url'           :   'http://www.website.co.uk/whatWeDo.html',
        'urlSection'    :   '#whatWeDo' 
    },
    {   
        'loadInTo'      :    '#ourValues',
        'url'           :   'http://www.website.co.uk/ourValues.html',
        'urlSection'    :   '#ourValues' 
    },
    {   
        'loadInTo'      :    '#ourExpertise',
        'url'           :   'http://www.website.co.uk/ourExpertise.html',
        'urlSection'    :   '#ourExpertise' 
    }   
] }
```

I use this to load/ajax parts of other pages like this:

HTML

```
<div id="aboutUs" class="section"></div>
<div id="whatWeDo" class="section"></div>
<div id="ourValues" class="section"></div>
<div id="ourExpertise" class="section"></div>
```

JS

```
for(i=0; i < loadPages.pageData.length ; i++){
    var current = loadPages.pageData[i];
    $(current.urlSection).load(current.url);
}
```

This works just fine. However I would like to have the JSON stored in an external .JS file rather than being on the page.

I can load the JSON file but cannot get it into the same format as above here's how I'm approaching this:

```
window.siteMap = '';

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'js/siteMap.js',
    async: false,
    beforeSend: function(x) {
        if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
            x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
        }
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        siteMap = eval('(' + data + ')');
    }
});
```

In the console I can see the file has been loaded but I can reference the data in the same way. Can anyone help show me where I am going wrong? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I notice the mime-type is `application/j-son`, not `application\json`. Is that a typo?

Comment: @RB I got that from here http://www.jquery4u.com/json/ajaxjquery-getjson-simple/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not eval the data, use

```
$.parseJSON(data)
```

instead

EDIT:
 check your json validity with http://jsonlint.com/

$.parseJSON you need if your response is a string

Comment: thanks for your reply! I have tried this but when I try to reference siteMap.pageData it returns undefined

Comment: does your js file include only json data (without 'var loadPages=' )? and give your file .json extension not .js

Comment: yes it has just the json data I have also renamed the .js file .json but no change. In Google dev tools if I reference siteMap it returns __proto__ Object

Comment: where do you reference siteMap, can you post some more of your code? can you see in the console network tab your request and its content?

Comment: Once the page loads I type siteMap into Google Dev Tools in returns an Object. If reference the same data when it is on the page and not loaded via ajax it returns Object pageData: array[4]. In the network tab I can see my .json file.

Comment: well, 1. use "" instead of '' in your json, and in your response you are returning a json object, not a string - you don't need to convert it anymore, use it as is